# Specifying and automating raster clipping with overlaps using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I'm working with GeoTIFF rasters ~1000mx1000m (1m pixels), and would like to take clips of the raster that are 150mx150m, but where each clip has a 50m overlapping border with the adjacent clips on each side, meaning that each 50mx50m section of the tiff will be at the centre of an individual clip.

How do I do this?

I'm guessing there's a way to create overlapping vectors and then clip the tiff using each vector.

Comment: Create grid can create overlapping polygons